# How to use the values of TaskKey and SettingKey to define setting?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to compute both values from TaskKey (e.g. `unmanagedClasspath`) and SettingKey (e.g. `baseDirectory`), in order to define other setting `SettingKey`?

Current goal would be to define `sourceGenerators` according to defined dependencies (`classpath`) and other settings (`baseDirectory`, `sourceManaged`, ...).

Using only `SettingKey` can be done as following, but it doesn't work as-is to include `TaskKey` in the process:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (baseDirectory in Compile).
  zip(sourceManaged in Compile).map(settingsValues ⇒ ???)
```

Comment: Which version of sbt are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: It's not possible to set a SettingKey using TaskKeys. See [.sbt Build Definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html) and [More Kinds of Setting](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html) from the official documentation of sbt.

You could solve it by having following code (in sbt 0.12.4 and lower versions).

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (baseDirectory, sourceManaged, managedClasspath in Compile) map { (b, s, c) =>
  Seq[File]()
}
```

However I *highly* recommend using the newer versions of sbt that offer many simplifications for defining such relationship between settings and tasks (remember that tasks can be based upon the values of settings, but not vice versa).

For example using 0.13.5, you could do it as follows:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val b = baseDirectory.value
  val s = sourceManaged.value
  val c = (managedClasspath in Compile).value
  Seq[File]()
}.taskValue
```

Obviously, in this overly simplistic example the values `b`, `s` and `c` are discarded since they're not used to compute the last expression `Seq[File]()` that becomes the result value.

Comment: First snippet won't work as soon as you want to compute values from baseDirectory, sourceManaged & managedClasspath togather (get setting values from some, Task[T] for other, doesn't mix well). Second way is fine, I would just use `<+=` not to have to 'unwrap' define task. `sourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task { generateActorSystem(baseDirectory.value, sourceManaged.value,(managedClasspath in Compile).value) }`

Comment: @applicius just out of curiosity could you show an example where the first snipped doesn't work? What error do you get? I can for example output the content of all three values to the console.

Comment: It should not be possible to `.map` tuple `(SettingKey[File],SettingKey[File],TaskKey[Classpath])`, but indeed it works. I guess there is some magic implicit. I prefer the `Def.task { x.value }` way which is more explicit.

Comment: @applicius yeah there is some implicit magic, however I also prefer the way with `Def.task`. Either way if this is working for you, would you mind accepting it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I define a custom TaskKey assigned with a tuple gathering values from other SettingKey & TaskKey, and then I assign sourceGenerators mapping over this custom key. I don't know whether this a more direct way, not requiring to define such temporary custom key.

```
val generatorsConfig = TaskKey[(File, File, Classpath)](
  "reactive-mongo-generators-config", "Source generators configuration")

generatorsConfig := (
  (baseDirectory in Compile).value,
  (sourceManaged in Compile).value, 
  (managedClasspath in Compile).value)

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= generatorsConfig map { d =>
  val (base, managed, cp) = d
  Seq[File]() // Define according base, managed and classpath
}
```